# Spark - How to exclude partitions while recovering partitions

Tags: pyspark, partition

Our hive table is partitioned by date and partitions are recovered every-time after the ETL process is completed. We want to maintain only latest 6 months partition while recovering the partitions.
How can we do it without dropping the partitions manually. Table is accessed through athena

Comment: What kind of table is it? Hive/delta? If delta, then would `VACCUME` work for you?

Comment: It's Hive table accessed through Athena.